# Android ip cameraX, camera2 in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, video-streaming, android-wifi, android-camera2, android-camerax

I quite new to android video recording and sharing.

Let say I've got two Android devices D1 and D2

In D1 I split screen in to do parts, in the top part I display camera view from D1(cameraX), and in the bottom part of the screen I need to get camera view from D2. Devices are connected to the same wifi network.
How to stream video from D2 to D1 using same wifi network?
It is possible using cameraX?

The lowest app API is 23

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in Android APIs for easily streaming video data from one device to another.  You could see if you can use [WebRTC](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/android/) or similar to make your life easier.

You can certainly use CameraX to get the camera frames from D1 and D2's cameras - for example, on D2, the ImageAnalysis use case will give you YUV frames you should be able to pass into WebRTC and over to D1.

Comment: Hi Eddy, Thanks for your answer. It looks like u r good in camx. So i would like to ask you another question. I have another problem for now. In our project we need to migrate from camera2 to cameraX. Since android 10 we've a lot of bug reports in slowmotion recording with camera2. Do you know how to record high speed videos in cameraX?

Comment: There's no current support for high-speed video recording in CameraX, as far as I know. I'd file a feature request with CameraX or see if there's an existing one.